# WPF Rotating Opacity Mask

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, vector

Is it possible to rotate an opacity mask for a XAML  using a  ?  I am trying to create a "busy spinner" affect similar to the image below but with opacity instead of a rasterized image, animated gif or rotating the base graphic.

[image]

Comment: What are you using for the opacity mask? If it has a `RenderTransform`, you can rotate it in an animation.

Comment: If it were me, I'd ditch the idea of rotating an opacity mask and instead just do some simple coloranimations in a storyboard on some xaml paths, no raster image, pure xaml, easy peazy.

Comment: Avoid opacity masks like the plague.  They're performance killers.